# Linking to winmm.dll in Visual Studio 2013 Express for mciSendString

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to use mciSendString in visual studio express 2013 (Visual C++) but I keep getting an error

```
Error   1   error C3861: 'mciSendStringA': identifier not found
```

I assume this i because I have not linked to the correct dll, but I cannot find any details online or on msdn about how to link to the dll. It seems quite strange that there wouldn't be more obvious documentation about this. Can someone tell me how to link to the dll?

EDIT:

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mmsystem.h>

extern char command1[] = "open C:\\boing.mp3 type MPEGVideo alias 0";
extern char command2[] = "play 0 from 0";

int main()
{
    mciSendStringA(command1, NULL, 0, 0);
    mciSendStringA(command2, NULL, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: It is a compile error, not a link error.  You probably forgot `#include <mmsystem.h>`.

Comment: Hmm, no I have included <mmsystem.h> and <Windows.h>

Comment: You'd better have a look at mmsystem.h, it might have been damaged.

Answer (score 3):

To make `mciSendString()` to work, you need to link to `winmm.lib`.

Just adding `winmm.lib` to `Project Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies` will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've been trying to find where to add the library but I still can't find any documentation about it. Do you know how this is done with Visual Studio Express 2013?

Comment: Hmm its very strange, I actually had found that menu and tried that to no avail. Since that menu just has a text box (instead of a file chooser dialog) you just type in the name of library right? Do you have to include the full path? Just below under "Inherited values" it lists kernel32.lib with no path.

Comment: @Mike2012 You don't need to incude its full path. Make sure the values is something like `winmm.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)` after you adding it to Additional Dependencies.

Comment: it looks exactly like: winmm.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies) but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `mmsystem.h` (admittedly from the V7.1A Windows SDK, which is the most recent I have installed), I can see that there's a `#ifdef _WIN32` block in there. If `_WIN32` is not defined, then `mciSendStringA` is not declared. Instead `mciSendString` is declared.

Check your project options and ensure that both `WIN32` and `_WIN32` are defined. I'm guessing that you started from a console project, rather than a Windows Application project, and that at least one of those isn't defined.

Comment: IS this something that would be in Project > Properties? Sorry I don't usually use Visual Studio.